# Inactive tomcat.service in Centos 7

Tags: tomcat7, centos7

Very new to Linux and currently tasked to install tomcat 7 in centos 7 os.

I followed the instruction here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-centos-7-via-yum

Everything seems to be ok and did not get any errors but as soon as I run sudo systemctl status tomcat

It shows that the tomcat.service is Active: Inactive (Dead)

I opened the catalina.out to see error messages but it is not showing any error. Would appreciate any help to nudge me to the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Any progress on this issue? How did you manage to resolve it? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error as above, do you have a answer for this? 
And I had searched to fix this issue for two days, but still not fixed yet.

Comment: Any progress on this issue? How did you manage to resolve it? Please suggest.